# How to use Replace/Substitution function in PL SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, replace, listagg

I've a doubt regarding replacing / substituting values in PLSQL. I've used listagg to segregate n number of values with each and every value being splitted by comma delimiter.

```
select listagg(column_name,',') with group (order by column_name)
Into new_variable
from table
```

For instance when executing the above query it returns 7digit alpha numeric values.
For example

ABCD123,EFGH456,IJKL789

After storing the above values in a variable. When trying to replace the comma (,) with this (',') using replace function.

```
Select replace(new_variable,',','','')
From dual;
```

It returns the error invalid number of arguments. Is there anyway other than replace function to replace (,) with (','). Thanking you in advance.

Desired output:
ABCD123','EFGH456','IJKL789

Comment: Can you add the desired output example to the question?

Comment: do you want to pass the output to another query IN clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The escape is either a `q'`  or 3 `'` s
If you wanted to do it in the listagg:

```
 select '('|| listagg(col,''',''') WITHIN  GROUP  (order by 1) ||')'
```

If you want the braces

Comment: Is there a way to add (' infront and ') at last, because what you shared is working like a charm

Comment: With the help of your insight, now I'm able to segregate as needed. One more help, is there a way to add (' in front and ') at last, so the output variable can be passed as a input in next anonymous block.
`Select  listagg(dctd_acli.acid,''',''') within group (order by tran_id,tran_date)
--into    v_acid1
from    tbaadm.dctd_acli,
        tbaadm.gam
where   dctd_acli.acid = gam.acid
and     tran_id = '  S123551'
and     tran_date = '01-JUL-19';`

Output which I'm getting: UB39608','UB39752','UB42006','UB42007','UB42281','UB42803','UB42803','UB42806

Comment: Yes you can, just append the '(' and prepend ')', I have updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

[REPLACE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions134.htm).

Are you looking for this?

```
Select replace('ABCD123,EFGH456,IJKL789',',',q'[',']') From dual;
```

OUTPUT

```
ABCD123','EFGH456','IJKL789
```

Comment: Yes exactly like this.